# App crashes after adding ScrollView to my XML layout file

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I'm trying to add a ScrollView. Everything was working until I added a ScrollView to my XML layout file, then my app gets crashed. How can I solve this issue? Please can you suggest me how can I solve add ScrollView to my Layout without making too many changes to my Views attributes specially ImageView of id  `@+id/mediaImage` should be `wrap_content`.

Here is the XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/CardViewBgColor"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/searchCardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/searchUrl"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:hint="@string/search_url_hint" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/search_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:onClick="getMediaID"
                android:text="@string/button_search_text" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/imageCardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/profileImage"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/testimage" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/profileUsername"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:text="username"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                    android:textSize="24sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/mediaImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingStart="16dp"
                android:paddingEnd="16dp"
                android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                android:src="@drawable/testimage" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/caption"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingStart="16dp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:paddingEnd="16dp"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:text="Capion Text"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the crash log:

> 2020-05-20 13:00:26.506 20685-20685/com.trickdarinda.instaphotodownloader E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.trickdarinda.instaphotodownloader, PID: 20685
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.trickdarinda.instaphotodownloader/com.trickdarinda.instaphotodownloader.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #46: ScrollView can host only one direct child
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2946)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
>        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #46: ScrollView can host only one direct child
>        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child
>           at android.widget.ScrollView.addView(ScrollView.java:279)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:871)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:870)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:519)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
>           at com.trickdarinda.instaphotodownloader.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7224)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7213)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2926)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)

Comment: add crash log please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ScrollView can have only one child, you need to  wrap all the childviews in  LinearLayout , that should fix it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/CardViewBgColor"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/searchCardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/searchUrl"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:hint="@string/search_url_hint" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/search_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:onClick="getMediaID"
                android:text="@string/button_search_text" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/imageCardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/profileImage"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/testimage" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/profileUsername"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:text="username"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                    android:textSize="24sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/mediaImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingStart="16dp"
                android:paddingEnd="16dp"
                android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                android:src="@drawable/testimage" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/caption"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingStart="16dp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:paddingEnd="16dp"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:text="Capion Text"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
  </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I've tried but now the ImageView has taken unnecessary spaces. You can see here ' https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SajnSXBUqFm87dAHBcEu14Au8iWiummk/view?usp=sharing'

Comment: Yes it is vertical

Comment: But when I'm trying to run it it shows a preview like the image in the link I've given above

Answer (score 1):

A `ScrollView` can have only one child! Just wrap all the CardViews in a vertical `LinearLayout`, that should fix it.

As a general note, you should look at the crash log - IIRC it would say something along the lines of "your scrollview has more than one child"

Answer (score 0):

A `ScrollView` can have only one child. Wrap your `CardView` in a parent layout, e.g `LinearLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/CardViewBgColor"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/searchCardView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp">
            ...
    </LinearLayout>

<ScrollView>
```

Comment: I've tried but now the ImageView has taken unnecessary spaces. You can see here ' https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SajnSXBUqFm87dAHBcEu14Au8iWiummk/view?usp=sharing'

Comment: That's because you set the ImageView's height to wrap_content. You have to set a fixed height to the image and set the scaleType to either fitCenter or centerCrop depending on whether you want to show the whole image or crop it.